# Ошибка при загрузке документа Вконтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Добрый день.

У меня не получается загрузить документ в ВК.

Мои шаги:

1. Получаю URL для загрузки методом getUploadUrlWall()
2. Отправляю multipartom файл
3. Получаю file и сохраняю его методом docsSave()

В чём ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь код в вопрос

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не вижу смысла добавлять код.

Comment: ты мог там накосячить. или ты идеально пишешь всё с первого раза, а косяки всегда у внешних API, библиотек и языков программирования?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, данный код работал пару дней назад и перестал работать сейчас. Порядок действий я описал, ВК даже возвращает FILE, а потом отказывается его сохранять.

Comment: Раз всё работало, а тут вдруг не работает, то тебе надо в поддержку вк и обратиться. Это более логично, не правда ли? Без кода можно только на кофейной гуще гадать.. Но дело твоё